# About Empty/Blank database field in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I am confusing a lot, about, Empty, Null and not Null database fields value.
I have a tab where is several fields are containing Empty/blank data some of them containing NULL data, and containing actual data.
I am confuse what the difference between Epmyt/Blank and Null data.

Please help me.

Thanks
Ravik

Answer (score 1):

Empty or blank usually refers to an empty string value, length = 0 characters.  Null means no value, not even an empty one.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is a database indicator that specifies that the value in the database is missing or indeterminate.  Empty strings are zero-length varchar strings.

They may or may not be the same when you select values.  SQL Server Management Studio, for instance, exports NULL values as "NULL" instead of a blank string.

NULLs follow some very basic comparison rules that many find counterintuitive.  Any comparison operation -- except for `is null` -- returns false.  In particular, the following two return false:

```
where NULL = NULL
where NULL <> NULL
```

This applies to columns that have a NULL value as well  So these both return false, when `val` contains a NULL value:

```
where val = val
where val <> val
```

Blank/empty string is just a value for a variable length string that has a length of 0, usually represented as ''.  The following does return true:

```
where '' = ''
where val = val                  -- given that val is ''
```

The one complication is that some databases treat NULL values as zero-length strings.  Oracle comes to mind.  However, this is not ANSI-compliant behavior.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is different from an empty value in that with NULL, you don't know for sure if the value is empty or not. This has real measurable impacts in your database. Here are some examples:

- The `LEN()` of an empty varchar field is 0. The `LEN()` of a NULL field is still NULL... you don't know how large the field is.
- Two empty fields compared to themselves (`'' = ''`) are true. You don't know if two NULL fields are equal or not, so (`NULL = NULL`) results in NULL.
- The `COALESCE('', ... )` of an empty field results in the empty field. The `COALESCE(NULL, ... )` of a NULL field falls through to the next value.

There are many more examples like this. NULL does *not* mean empty. NULL means "I don't know."